# Array to Linked List C

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to convert an array to an linked list.
so basically, im gonna have a structure called "head" which will be the first element
and node, which will be the other elements.
any ideas so i can it started?

Comment: @Blagovest - Actually, "why" is the question ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any solution simpler than just iterating through the array and appending the elements to the list.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to implement linked lists in C is with a single node structure containing a data member and a next pointer. Every time you want a new node, `malloc` space for it and set the next pointer of the last node in the list to point to it. The last node's next pointer should point to `NULL`.

You only have to hold onto a regular pointer to the first element. That's your head pointer.

Comment: im not allowed to use malloc. so i will just point to it. it is possible right?

Comment: @shadow7: it's *possible*, but it's not very elegant or practical and it will have constraints such as maximum number of nodes - you'll probably just want to have an array of nodes if you can't use malloc, so you might as well just stick with the array that you started out with.

Comment: @shadow7: What Paul said. There's no point in using linked lists if you can't allocate memory at runtime. They'll be slower and bigger than their array counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

Without using malloc you won't be able to easily add a new node to store data in so its best to just use the array to avoid the mess (but why can't you use malloc now?)

Comment: Why did you revive a homework question that's nearing two years old since last reply?